# Extend image repeating horizontal line and repeating vertical line on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, stretch

I have image and in that image i want to repeat horizontal and vertical line, so i extend my image.

For example i have image 50X50, and i want it to be 50x70, by repeating line x = 15. Is this even possible on iOS?

EDIT:

Ok i'll try to be more clear. I have image 60x60, which is rectangle basically, with width 60 and height 60. Now i want to streach that image to be 80x60, by repeating pixles with x = 40. Or to draw it simply, i have:

```
  123456
1 XXXAXX
2 XXXAXX
3 XXXAXX
4 XXXAXX
5 XXXAXX
6 XXXAXX
```

and i want it to be:

```
  12345678
1 XXXAAAXX
2 XXXAAAXX
3 XXXAAAXX
4 XXXAAAXX
5 XXXAAAXX
6 XXXAAAXX
```

I repeat all pixels on image that are on the line 40. And i want to do it on any number of images.

Comment: pls add more detail with screen shot....

Comment: Can you please post the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you should use:

`(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets`

> UIEdgeInsets is structure that specifies float values for each cap
>   inset: top, left, bottom and right areas of an image. To apply this to
>   the image for the button, here is all we need to do:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton"]  
   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];
```

> This requests that the left and right 16 pixels of the original image
>   are not scaled or resized when stretching the image to accomodate the
>   button size frame defined above. The end

OBS: This only work well for plain images, for example images with gradient will not work well.

Take a look [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 8):

The key to achieving your desired result is `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` on `UIImage`. For example, take the following 50px by 50px image (Note: this is the @2x version):

[image: Retina-scale 50x50 image with a single pixel vertical red line offset by 15px in the x-axis]

If you want to stretch the red line horizontal, you first define a `UIEdgeInset` that describes the position of the red line:

```
UIEdgeInsets redLine = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 34);
```

This defines a one-pixel wide slice of the image offset by 15px from the left. The `right` offset is `34` because the right edge of the stretchable slice is at 16px and 50 (image width) minus 16 is 34.

Now that we have the `UIEdgeInset`, we can load the image and create a stretchable version of it:

```
UIImage *stretchableImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:redLine];
```

We can assign this `stretchableImage` to a `UIImageView` with the frame that we need:

```
UIImageView *stretchedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stretchableImage];
stretchedImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,70,50); // The image view is 70px wide
```

In the app, `stretchedImageView` will look like this:

[image]

There's another method called `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` that allows you to **tile** the image slice rather than stretch it, so you can do crazy things like take this image:

[image]

And tile it horizontally like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat an image in UIImageView like this:

```
var dottedLineView : UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dashedLine"))

    return view
}()
```